# prisma how to datetime instead of datetime(3)

Tags: prisma

my model is like this

```js
model Activated {
    created        DateTime @default(now())

    @@map(name: "activated")
}
```

after the db push, my sql is like this

```sql
`created` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
```

I do not want the `(3)` how to tell prisma not to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

this schema.prisma:

```
model Activated {
    created0          DateTime?        @db.DateTime(0)
    created1          DateTime?        @db.DateTime(1)
    created2          DateTime?        @db.DateTime(2)
    created3          DateTime?        @db.DateTime(3) // DATETIME(3) is default mapping
    // ...
}
```

would in MySQL  generate:

```
    created0    datetime
    created1    datetime(1)
    created2    datetime(2)
    created3    datetime(3)
```

Comment: My text got somehow restructured by stackoverflow, but hopefully it is clear and I hope it helps. Have a great day.